# Crystal Reports XI: Drawing Boxes Programmatically

Tags: drawing, shapes, crystal-reports-xi

Is it possible to draw shapes in Crystal Reports XI programmatically?

Specifically I would like to be able to draw boxes around individual letters, which would allow me to duplicate a pen+paper form that has boxes which would be filled in.

My current method is to individually draw each box, using the "Insert Box" tool. This is a lengthy process which could be speed up considerably if I could handle this all in code.

If I am not able to code these boxes does anyone know of a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: So, you want to display a string with each letter surrounded by a box? This can be done of course, but there's no way I know of to automate it.  All I can suggest is copy&paste.

Comment: Sure could do with an answer for this?  Did you get a solution?